# Set text aligment on the right side

Tags: css

I have table with left text alignment. How I can only set the checkbox to be with right text alignment?

```
    <h:panelGroup styleClass="table-right">
           <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.method}"> </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
     </h:panelGroup>

    .table-right {
        text-align: right;
    }
```

**HTML output:**

```
    <tr>
    <td>Security Question</td>
    <td><textarea id="form:securityquestion" name="form:securityquestion" cols="60" rows="3" onblur="mojarra.ab(this,event,'blur',0,'form:securityquestionvalidator')"></textarea><span id="form:securityquestionvalidator"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Security Answer</td>
    <td><textarea id="form:securityanswer" name="form:securityanswer" cols="60" rows="3" onblur="mojarra.ab(this,event,'blur',0,'form:securityanswervalidator')"></textarea><span id="form:securityanswervalidator"></span></td>
    </tr>
```

Is there any solution to change just the cell alignment of the checkbox with CSS?

Comment: Why your HTML output has no checkbox?

Comment: text-align:rigth??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.table-right input[type="checkbox"] {
  float: right;
}
```

This should align your checkbox to right

Comment: Thanks! It's working. Why it's not working with the other solutions?

Comment: Inside table checkbox can be aligned only by float. I don't think text-align will work for that

Answer (score 0):

This css is not working

```
.table-right {
    text-align: rigth;
}
```

because you have typo `rigth` is not word. It must be `right`.

Answer (score 0):

Use correct typo as in place of [text-align: rigth]

```
.table-right {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to paste `styleClass="table-right"` to `selectBooleanCheckbox` section. And Try to use !important rule on css.

Like: `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox styleClass="table-right" value="#{bean.method}"> </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>`

```
.table-right {
        text-align: right !important;
    }
```